# XSLT 2.0 multiple levels in one group

Tags: xslt

Question is how do i get my desired output?

I successfully created a group for each `<LogistiekeDeelEenheid>`
however, the `<DeeleenheidAantal>` field must also be filled with one value. For `<LogistiekeDeelEenheid>` 000094 `<DeeleenheidAantal>` has to be filled with 10 from `<Value AttributeID = "att_NumberInCombiProduct"> 10 </Value>` in the xsl to transform. And `<LogistiekeDeelEenheid>` 000072 `<DeeleenheidAantal>` has to be filled with 20 from `<Value AttributeID = "att_NumberInCombiProduct"> 20 </Value>` And `<LogistiekeDeelEenheid>` 000032 `<DeeleenheidAantal>` has to be filled with 35 from `<Value AttributeID = "att_NumberInCombiProduct"> 35 </Value>`

The xml to transform:

```
<Test>
    <Product ID="LV-10432200" UserTypeID="CombiLogistiekeVariant">
        <Name>1 - TEST1</Name>
        <ProductCrossReference ProductID="Product-10430948"
            Type="rpp_CombiLogistiekeVariant2Product">
            <KeyValue KeyID="key_ProductGTIN">2311111</KeyValue>
            <KeyValue KeyID="key_Productnummer">000094</KeyValue>
            <MetaData>
                <Value AttributeID="att_AantalInCombiProduct">10</Value>
            </MetaData>
        </ProductCrossReference>
        <ProductCrossReference ProductID="Product-10431710"
            Type="rpp_CombiLogistiekeVariant2Product">
            <KeyValue KeyID="key_ProductGTIN">5449000018885</KeyValue>
            <KeyValue KeyID="key_Productnummer">000072</KeyValue>
            <MetaData>
                <Value AttributeID="att_AantalInCombiProduct">20</Value>
            </MetaData>
        </ProductCrossReference>
        <ProductCrossReference ProductID="Product-10431738"
            Type="rpp_CombiLogistiekeVariant2Product">
            <KeyValue KeyID="key_ProductGTIN">54419780</KeyValue>
            <KeyValue KeyID="key_Productnummer">000032</KeyValue>
            <MetaData>
                <Value AttributeID="att_AantalInCombiProduct" Changed="true">35
                </Value>
            </MetaData>
        </ProductCrossReference>
        <Values>
            <Value AttributeID="att_Productnummer">000001</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="att_LVStatus" ID="2">Inactief</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="att_LVOmschrijving">TEST Config 1</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="att_LVNummer">1</Value>
        </Values>
        <Product ID="Pack-10432212" UserTypeID="Kleinverpakking">
            <Name>21 - Kleinverpakking</Name>
            <ProductCrossReference ProductID="LV-10432200"
                Type="rpp_Verpakking-Kleinverpakking2Kleiner">
                <MetaData>
                    <Value AttributeID="att_AantalInVerpakking">1</Value>
                </MetaData>
            </ProductCrossReference>
            <Values>
                <Value AttributeID="att_VerpakkingBreedte" UnitID="unece.unit.CMT">1</Value>
                <Value AttributeID="att_VerpakkingGewichtBruto" UnitID="181">1
                </Value>
                <Value AttributeID="att_LVNummer">1</Value>
                <Value AttributeID="att_VerpakkingHoogte" UnitID="unece.unit.CMT">1</Value>
                <Value AttributeID="att_Productnummer">000001</Value>
                <Value AttributeID="att_VerpakkingDiepte" UnitID="unece.unit.CMT">1</Value>
                <Value AttributeID="att_PrimaireGTIN" Derived="true">Primaire GTIN
                    Ontbreekt
                </Value>
            </Values>
        </Product>
    </Product>
</Test>
```

And must be transformed to:

```
                    <LogistiekeDeelEenheid>
                        <DeeleenheidArtikelNummer>000094</DeeleenheidArtikelNummer>
                        <DeeleenheidLogistiekeVariant>0</DeeleenheidLogistiekeVariant>
                        <DeeleenheidCode>1</DeeleenheidCode>
                        <DeeleenheidLinkType>4</DeeleenheidLinkType>
                        <DeeleenheidAantal>10</DeeleenheidAantal>
                    </LogistiekeDeelEenheid>
                    <LogistiekeDeelEenheid>
                        <DeeleenheidArtikelNummer>000072</DeeleenheidArtikelNummer>
                        <DeeleenheidLogistiekeVariant>0</DeeleenheidLogistiekeVariant>
                        <DeeleenheidCode>1</DeeleenheidCode>
                        <DeeleenheidLinkType>4</DeeleenheidLinkType>
                        <DeeleenheidAantal>20</DeeleenheidAantal>
                    </LogistiekeDeelEenheid>
                    <LogistiekeDeelEenheid>
                        <DeeleenheidArtikelNummer>000032</DeeleenheidArtikelNummer>
                        <DeeleenheidLogistiekeVariant>0</DeeleenheidLogistiekeVariant>
                        <DeeleenheidCode>1</DeeleenheidCode>
                        <DeeleenheidLinkType>4</DeeleenheidLinkType>
                        <DeeleenheidAantal>35</DeeleenheidAantal>
                    </LogistiekeDeelEenheid>
```

My xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
            <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Test/Product"/>
    </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="Test/Product">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="//ProductCrossReference[@Type='rpp_CombiLogistiekeVariant2Product']" group-by="//ProductCrossReference/KeyValue[@KeyID='key_Productnummer']">
            <xsl:variable select="current-grouping-key()" name="Productnummer"/>
       <test>
           <xsl:value-of select="../Name"/>
       </test>
        <LogistiekeDeelEenheid>
            <DeeleenheidArtikelNummer>
                <xsl:value-of select="$Productnummer"/>
            </DeeleenheidArtikelNummer>
            <DeeleenheidLogistiekeVariant>0</DeeleenheidLogistiekeVariant>
            <DeeleenheidCode>1</DeeleenheidCode>
            <DeeleenheidLinkType>4</DeeleenheidLinkType>
            <DeeleenheidAantal>
                <xsl:value-of select="../ProductCrossReference/MetaData/Value[@AttributeID='att_AantalInCombiProduct']"/>
            </DeeleenheidAantal>
        </LogistiekeDeelEenheid>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But if i use this code, i get this result what is incorrect. In the first  should be 10 in the second 20 and in the third 35

```
<?xml encoding="UTF-8" version="1.0"?>
<test>1 - TEST1</test>
<LogistiekeDeelEenheid>
   <DeeleenheidArtikelNummer>000094</DeeleenheidArtikelNummer>
   <DeeleenheidLogistiekeVariant>0</DeeleenheidLogistiekeVariant>
   <DeeleenheidCode>1</DeeleenheidCode>
   <DeeleenheidLinkType>4</DeeleenheidLinkType>
   <DeeleenheidAantal>10 20 35
                </DeeleenheidAantal>
</LogistiekeDeelEenheid>
<test>1 - TEST1</test>
<LogistiekeDeelEenheid>
   <DeeleenheidArtikelNummer>000072</DeeleenheidArtikelNummer>
   <DeeleenheidLogistiekeVariant>0</DeeleenheidLogistiekeVariant>
   <DeeleenheidCode>1</DeeleenheidCode>
   <DeeleenheidLinkType>4</DeeleenheidLinkType>
   <DeeleenheidAantal>10 20 35
                </DeeleenheidAantal>
</LogistiekeDeelEenheid>
<test>1 - TEST1</test>
<LogistiekeDeelEenheid>
   <DeeleenheidArtikelNummer>000032</DeeleenheidArtikelNummer>
   <DeeleenheidLogistiekeVariant>0</DeeleenheidLogistiekeVariant>
   <DeeleenheidCode>1</DeeleenheidCode>
   <DeeleenheidLinkType>4</DeeleenheidLinkType>
   <DeeleenheidAantal>10 20 35
                </DeeleenheidAantal>
</LogistiekeDeelEenheid>
```

Comment: Consider to cut sample data to the minimum to demonstrate the problem and also describe verbally what you want to achieve. XSLT snippets that don't do the job don't suffice to do what you want to achieve.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I have adjusted my question/ sample data. Hope it is clearer

Comment: it is not. Please reduce your code to the minimum necessary to reproduce your problem and make it **complete** - i.e. something that can be copied and run as is. See: [mcve].

Comment: It is not quite clear why you say you want to group but `xsl:for-each-group select="(../../Product[@UserTypeID='CombiLogistiekeVariant'])[1]"` seems to select a single element as the grouping population. In the sample data it doesn't look as if the key expression `ProductCrossReference/KeyValue[@KeyID='key_Productnummer']` would give any duplicates. So it doesn't seem as if you need to group at all, rather process the `ProductCrossReference` elements directly. Or group them instead of the single Product, then select `MetaData/Value[@AttributeID='att_AantalInCombiProduct']`.

Comment: I have adjusted the example, so this is the minimum to reproduce. I know it's not properly to use // but for now....It's just a small part of an entire xslt

Comment: I have adjusted the example, so this is the minimum to reproduce. I know it's not properly to use // but for now....It's just a small part of an entire xslt.  I have made a for-each-group for @Type='rpp_CombiLogistiekeVariant2Product'] but in the group i have to select <Value AttributeID="att_AantalInCombiProduct">10</Value> to fill the tag <DeeleenheidAantal>. The result i'm getting now is <DeeleenheidAantal>10 20 35</DeeleenheidAantal>

Comment: If you are still struggling to solve this with the suggestions made then please edit your question and provide a minimum but well-formed and complete input sample, your current sample has no root element but two `Product` elements and it is not clear whether they are siblings or whether they are nested.

Comment: Yes, still struggling and meanwhile quite frustrated, because i'm struggling. I have adapted the question

Comment: The answer I posted does create the three values you have asked for now in your edited description (e.g. "``<LogistiekeDeelEenheid> 000094 <DeeleenheidAantal>` has to be filled with 10").

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thank you for your help. Indeed it works, i'm happy about that. Now i have to make it work in the whole xslt, Yes there is a lot of nesting in the xml. I have to deal with it, no choice there.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion I made in the comment, adjusted to the code you have posted later, would result in

```
    <xsl:template match="Test/Product">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="ProductCrossReference[@Type='rpp_CombiLogistiekeVariant2Product']" 
        group-by="KeyValue[@KeyID='key_Productnummer']">
        <xsl:variable select="current-grouping-key()" name="Productnummer"/>
   <test>
       <xsl:value-of select="../Name"/>
   </test>
    <LogistiekeDeelEenheid>
        <DeeleenheidArtikelNummer>
            <xsl:value-of select="$Productnummer"/>
        </DeeleenheidArtikelNummer>
        <DeeleenheidLogistiekeVariant>0</DeeleenheidLogistiekeVariant>
        <DeeleenheidCode>1</DeeleenheidCode>
        <DeeleenheidLinkType>4</DeeleenheidLinkType>
        <DeeleenheidAantal>
            <xsl:value-of select="MetaData/Value[@AttributeID='att_AantalInCombiProduct']"/>
        </DeeleenheidAantal>
    </LogistiekeDeelEenheid>
</xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
```

At https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ei5R4tY I applied the suggestion to your edited input sample and the result has e.g. `<DeeleenheidAantal>10</DeeleenheidAantal>`, that is, single values for that item in the result.

I must admit that your sample data with the nesting is still not clear to me but feel free to further edit your question and clarify which data you want to process and group.

Comment: Thank you for your help. For this part it works, i'm happy about that. Now i have to make it work in the whole xslt, Yes there is a lot of nesting in the xml. I have to deal with it, no choice there.